# Crystal Report Viewer in ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report, viewer, subreport

```
 /aspnet_client/System_Web/2_0_50727/CrystalReportWebFormViewer4
```

We've an ASP.NET web application with the SAP Crystal Report Viewer inside to show Crystal reports that we have in the application. We are trying to determine if we have a problem with our Crystal Reports or with the Crystal Report Viewer. We created some reports with sub-reports in them, load them into our application. Whenever we try to run a report with sub-reports in the report viewer it gives errors and fails. This has never been a problem for any of our other reports without sub reports in them.

We have created the reports with subreports where the procedures are external. We also tried embedding the sub-reports within the reports. We also tried having the sub-reports called or sending parameters to the sub-reports. None of them seem to help.

Error#1

> is that there are too many arguments in the stored procedure - but
>   when we checked our application it has the same number of arguments.

Error#2 was:

```
'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Train\Reports\Rpt_PublicSafetyProposed.rpt' could not be loaded!  The error message is: Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length#### at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy) at reportdisplay.ConfigureReportParameters() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Train\reportdisplay.aspx.vb:line 58 at reportdisplay.ConfigureCrystalReports() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Train\reportdisplay.aspx.vb:line 22
```

The reports work on our developers machine running it out of Visual Studio as a Crystal Report Project. On two different machines. However, when we try to run it through the crystal report viewer in the application, **they most often give Error#1**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing a Database, Verify Database on your report in Crystal Reports? It could be out-of-sync with your database.

Also, as an alternative to creating your own web viewer, check out Report Runner Web Portal at http://reportrunner.com.